# word for something that somebody likes to rant about frequently

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm sure there's a word for this that I've forgotten. I'm looking for an English term for something that somebody likes to rant about frequently. The closest I can come is "hobby horse" but it isn't specific enough: it means something that somebody likes to *talk* about a lot, rather than specifically rant.

Something that could work well in the sentence "I'll never quit this [word here]" because I like to rant about it. For hobby horse I had a similar sentence in mind: "I'll never get off this hobby horse" but of course "get off" only works because of the word "horse".

Comment: You could say 'I will never quit this rant', in which you are not referring to ranting on a variety of topics, but you are referring to a particular favourite topic which has become one, long continuous rant.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the speaker is unlikely to identify their *own* behaviour as ranting [otherwise the obvious solution would be "I'll never quit this *rant*"]. That being the case, the most likely "soft" description would actually be "hobby horse". And you can *quit* a hobby horse, in the sense of leaving it, or walking away from it.

Comment: "bugaboo" -----

Comment: to rant about something is negative. To talk about something all the time is not necessarily negative. Do you really mean rant??

Answer (score 3):

"I'll never quit this [**crusade**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crusade)."

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : a remedial enterprise undertaken with zeal and enthusiasm
> // a *crusade* against drunk driving

Of course, crusades (as with any other noun I can think of) can be "waged" in any number of ways, but talking about a cause at length is certainly common.

Answer (score 2):

[***Pet peeve***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_peeve)

minor annoyance that an individual identifies as particularly irritating to them, to a greater degree than would be expected based on the experience of others.

**His pet peeve was drivers who don't use their blinkers**.

***[tirade](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tirade)***

a prolonged outburst of bitter, outspoken denunciation

**He often held tirades about unsanitary practices**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think that phrase doesn't fully work because it doesn't imply liking to talk about it (somebody could privately hold a pet peeve, I think). I updated my question with a suggested sentence to contain it.

Comment: Well, then, maybe the second suggestion?

Comment: I appreciate the effort! The problem with tirade is just that it’s something that somebody does, potentially only once. Neither of these are closer than hobby horse, which is both a thing that somebody discusses and, by implication, one they frequently discuss.

Comment: @Stephen Well, if you don't like pet peeve, you probably do not mean rant. You mean: go on and on about something: talk about it ceaselessly. It must be your favorite ***topic***.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

> I'll never get off this **soapbox**.

With the context provided as part of the conversation, the soapbox can be understood as applying to the specific topic, instead of as a general oratory platform.

> **soapbox** *noun*
>   soap·box | \ˈsōp-ˌbäks  \
>   : an improvised platform used by a self-appointed, spontaneous, or informal orator
>   broadly : something that provides an outlet for delivering opinions
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soapbox</sup>

Answer (score -1):

a **dog whistle**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dog+whistle) noun

2. The use of term(s) that seem innocuous but is intended to convey a hidden and potentially controversial message to a particular audience(s).

As in:

> "I'll never quit this [word here]" because I like to rant about it.

to

This **dog whistle** issue caused unrelenting rants from X.

and

> ... against which he played the “law-and-order” ploy with his
>   **dog-whistle rants** about dangerous inner-cities, terrorist refugees, and criminal immigrants. [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=rdwnDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA206&ots=tHSwcOK8GQ&dq=%22dog%20whistle%20rants%22&pg=PA206#v=onepage&q=%22dog%20whistle%20rants%22&f=false)